# can I add a status bar in a windows form data grid view tool?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I wanted to add a status bar in a data grid view tool kinda like this.

[image]

is it possible to add such a column? if not what are the alternatives that I could do for this kind of thing?

Comment: It is already included when your fetching data from a database.

Comment: You can use the CellPainting event to paint even more complex status idicators based on the cell values..

Comment: @Vince Garcia, is any update. Please check if my answer works for you.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT hi, sorry I didn't realize that this got an answer I just tried it and it's working nicely. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the backcolor of the cell based on the conditions in your specific column.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "Age");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "Status");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test1", 22, "Normal");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test2", 23, "Risk");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test3", 26, "Abnormal");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                string value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "Normal":
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        break;

                    case "Risk":
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "Abnormal":
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    default:
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Result:

[image]